# Optimizing Image Loading in React + Vite : Reducing Latency for Large Images Stored in Public Directory

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

I have developed a React + Vite web application  in vercel. However, upon initial page load, the image takes about 12 seconds to display (approximately 2.4 MB) , causing poor user experience.

How can I optimize the loading process to drastically decrease this delay, especially when dealing with images located in the 'public' directory?".

[image]

[image]

```
export default function MyImg({ containerStyles }: ImgProps) {
    return (
        <div className={`${containerStyles}`}>
            <img src="/check.png" alt="Picture" className="object-contain" />
        </div>
    )
}
interface ImgProps {
    containerStyles: string;
}
```

This is my Image Component.

How can i reduce latency? and this also cause latency in loading svg which is behind this image.

```
<div className="hidden lg:flex relative">
                    <div className="bg-hero w-[500px] h-[500px] bg-no-repeat absolute -top-16 -right-8 overflow-hidden">
                        <MyImg containerStyles="w[-410px] h-[362px] bg-no-repeat relative -right-30" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```
.bg-hero {
    background-image: url(/pic-lob.svg;)
}
```

Comment: 2.4mb for a 500px image is very heavy indeed. I think you should look into image compression techniques and alternative formats (i.e. webp is smaller than png)

Comment: @SS87 Sure, I will look for compression and alternative format.